# UIScrollview not able to update height with use of contentSize programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am new for developing the ios application. I have tried to create a dynamic textFields(Auto Layout). but scroll its happen based on mentioned height only scroll enabled. if exceeds more specified height its will not scroll.
I have tried to change scrollview height with use of content size it will not update the height.

```
MainView
  ScrollView
    ContentView
```

I have added constraint top,bottom,left,right 0 to scrollview.
content view -  constraint width and height, top,bottom,left,right 0
equal Width to ScrollView.

So I have done add the textFields dynamically. if I have add 1 textFields means it has scroll upto what its added constraint height is 540.

Comment: Do you want to add textfields in the scrollview at run time or do you have fixed no. of textfields in the scrollview?

Comment: Yes I want text fields during at run time